# getting all email address that does not exists in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two List of objects like this:

```
List<EmployeeInfo> emp = getEmployees();
List<EmailList> emailist = getMasterList();
```

I want to get all the employees email address, firstname, lastName that exists in emailList, but do not exists in emp list. In other words, I want to exclude the email address of the users that exists in emp list. I wrote below LINQ to achieve this:

```
  List<EmployeeInfo> result = emp
                     .Where(w => !emailist.Contains(w.EmailAddress))
                        .ToList();
```

above keeps giving me an error saying "cannot convert from string to emailList.

This is the model for both employeeInfo and emailList

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateFormFilled { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; } = null!;

    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;

    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```
public partial class EmailList
{
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    public string? Eid { get; set; }

    public string? Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime LoadDate { get; set; }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var result = emailist .Where(p => !emp.Any(p2 => p2.EmailAddress == p.Email))
                .Select(o => new {
                    FirstName = o.FirstName,
                    LastName = o.LastName,
                    lastNEmailAddressame = o.Email
                }).ToList();
```

Example

EmployeeInfo:Test1@aaa.com,Test2@aaa.com

emailist:Test2@aaa.com,Test3@aaa.com

result:Test3@aaa.com

This emails is register two classess that the email: Test3@aaa.com exists in emailist but not in EmployeeInfo

```
 List<EmployeeInfo> emp = new List<EmployeeInfo>();
            emp.Add(new EmployeeInfo() { EmailAddress = "Test1@aaa.com", FirstName = "ddd" });
            emp.Add(new EmployeeInfo() { EmailAddress = "Test2@aaa.com", FirstName = "asa" });
            List<EmailList> emailist = new List<EmailList>();
            emailist.Add(new EmailList() { Email = "Test2@aaa.com", FirstName = "asa" });
            emailist.Add(new EmailList() { Email = "Test3@aaa.com", FirstName = "sdsdad" });
```